# PHP preg_replace_callback with multiple parameters

Tags: php, random, preg-replace-callback

I want to do a regex replace, but I don't want to do it every time it's found.  I think the preg_replace_callback is what I need to use, and just do my random check in there but I can't figure out how to pass the callback function multiple parameters.  I'll ultimately need more than two, but if I can get two work I can probably get more working.

For example I want to do the replace 50% of the time and the other times I'd just return what was found.  Here's a couple functions I've been working with, but just can't them right.

```
function pick_one($matches, $random) {
  $choices = explode('|', $matches[1]);
  return $random . $choices[array_rand($choices)];
}

function doSpin($content) {

 $call = array_map("pick_one", 50);
  return preg_replace_callback('!\[%(.*?)%\]!', $call, $content); 
/*  return preg_replace_callback('!\[%(.*?)%\]!', 'pick_one($1, 50)', $content);  */
}

$content = 'This [%should|ought|would|could%] make it much [%more convenient|faster|easier%] and help reduce duplicate content.';

echo doSpin($content).'<br/>';
```

Thanks
Allen

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly pass it multiple parameters. What you could do, however, is make the function a class method instead, and then create an instance of the class that has member properties set with the values you want to be available to the function (like `$random`).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function pick_one($groups) {

 // half of the time, return all options
  if (rand(0,1) == 1) {
    return $groups[1];
  };

  // the other half of the time, return one random option
  $choices = explode('|', $groups[1]);
  return $choices[array_rand($choices)];

}

function doSpin($content) {

  return preg_replace_callback('!\[%(.*?)%\]!', 'pick_one', $content); 

}

$content = 'This [%should|ought|would|could%] make it much [%more convenient|faster|easier%] and help reduce duplicate content.';

echo doSpin($content).'<br/>';
```